# Python:Group By Multiple Column Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I'm trying to group by a flattened data such as 2 columns group as list & the third one should be the sum of rows of that column .

Suppose data frame looks like

```
ColA      ColB     ColC     ColD
A         Hi       Hello     2
A         There    You       4
B         Okay     Tap       4
B         Bye      Here      6
```

I want the output dataframe to look like:

```
ColA     ColB        ColC          ColD
A       [Hi,There]   [Hello,You]    6
B       [Okay,Bye]   [Tap,Here]     10
```

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, try `groupby` with `agg` and a dictionary defining how to aggregate the columns:

```
df.groupby('ColA').agg({'ColB':list, 'ColC':list, 'ColD':'sum'})
```

Output:

```
             ColB          ColC  ColD
ColA                                 
A     [Hi, There]  [Hello, You]     6
B     [Okay, Bye]   [Tap, Here]    10
```

Answer (score 0):

This is one way to achieve your desired output:

```
df1 = df.groupby(['ColA'])['ColB','ColC'].agg(lambda x: list(x))
df1['ColD'] = df.groupby('ColA')['ColD'].sum()
df1 = df1.reset_index()
```

Output:

```
ColA    ColB         ColC           ColD
A       [Hi, There]  [Hello, You]   6
B       [Okay, Bye]  [Tap, Here]    10
```